3-valued logic and paradoxes of self-references
I am currently reading An Introduction to Non-classical Logic (2nd ed.) by Graham Priest. In section 7.7 of this book, it explains that when interpreting the three truth values of a three-valued logic—0, 1, and i—as "false," "true," and "both true and false," respectively, we can assign the truth value i to the statement "This sentence is false." This explanation seems plausible to me. But how about the following sentence?
S: "The truth value of this sentence is 0."

Semantically, sentence S seems equivalent to "This sentence is false." However, any truth value assigned to S results in a problem.

If the truth value of S is 1, then S is true, and thus, the truth value of this sentence is 0.
If the truth value of S is 0, then S is false, and thus, the truth value of this sentence is not 0.
If the truth value of S is i, then S is both true and false. However, the meaning of sentence S is that the truth value of S is 0. Assuming that the truth value of S is i, its truth value is not 0. Therefore, S is not true and is false.

All three cases seem to lead to unacceptable conclusions. Why is it that we can assign a truth value to one self-referential sentence but not to the other, even though they appear to have the same meaning? It seems that the difference may lie in a sentence referring to itself versus referring to its own truth value, yet this situation still feels paradoxical. While three-valued logic allows for a truth value representing a contradiction (both true and false), this seems to lead to a new type of contradiction. Even if we introduced a new truth value of "true and false and 'true and false'", similar contradictions would likely arise. Does this phenomenon generally occur in any n-valued logic systems? In other words, do n-valued logic systems that allow contradictions inevitably lead to new contradictions within the system?

The first item in your list has the truth value of the sentence as true and the second item has it as false, so why isn't it both true and false?

If it is both true and false, its truth value is i. In that case, S is false (and not true) because its truth value is not 0.

May I suggest that "true and false" is meaningless and "meaningless" (equivalently "category error" or "not a claim") is the correct way to represent the third value that a claim can have in the first place. The sentence "The sentence 'This sentence is meaningless' is meaningless" is true.

In Priest paraconsistent logic here, the conjunction of false and true are logically equivalent to the conjunction of true and false, so everything is consistent and fine after self-referencing (though note the calculus may not be sound), while after replacing with truth value explicitly in the same proposition, you are using their math values comparison to yield truth value of the same sentence after self-referencing which can only result false obviously. In summary with explicit variable you lost the conjunction connective’s power via conjunction-elimination rule during self-referencing…
